# Can one create Master pages in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Is there a way to create a master page in MS Word 2013 that will allow me to repeat the contents of the master page just like one can in MS Publisher or InDesign?

[EDITED]
I meant to have a content element, say an image and a footer, as a part of a master page. and then applying that master page to any page in the document where we wish to plug in the image and the footer. 
I didnt mean a central repository of all other documents.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is: [How to Create a Master Document in Word 2013](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office-for-mac/word-for-mac/how-to-create-a-master-document-in-word-2013/)

> Start a new, blank document in Word and save the document.
>
> Click the Outline button on the View tab. On the Outlining tab in the
>   Master Document group, click the Show Document button.
>
> More choices appear in the Master Document group. One of those choices
>   is the Insert button, used to build the master document. Click the
>   Insert button.
>
> You will see the Insert Subdocument dialog box.
>   Use the Insert Subdocument dialog box to hunt down the first document to insert into the master document.
>
> The documents must be inserted in order.
>   Click the Open button to stick the document into the master document.
>
> If you’re asked a question about conflicting styles, click the Yes to
>   All button. It keeps all subdocument styles consistent with the master
>   document. 8Save the master document when you’re done.
>
> At this point, the master document is created. You can edit the
>   headers and footers, create a table of contents, and work on other
>   items that affect the entire document.

Comment: I am afraid this is not what i meant. i meant to have a content element, say an image and a footer, as a part of a master page. and then applying that master page to any page in the document where we wish to plug in the image and the footer. i didnt mean a central repository of all other documents.

Comment: The better you describes your problem, the better it can be answered :) So you need somethinhg like template; i guess: http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/word/how-to-use-templates-in-word-2013/

Answer (score 0):

You can create Building Blocks for the various reusable elements (headers, footers, cover pages, images, etc.) and then save each in the appropriate gallery (Header Gallery, Footer Gallery, Cover Page Gallery, Table of Contents Gallery, QuickPart Gallery, and so on). I usually make these elements specific to one template file, but you can also save in Normal.dotm and other places. Then, when the template is applied to another document, those Building Blocks will become available for selection and insertion.

[Create and use content Building Blocks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-content-Building-Blocks-in-Word-2007-documents-0B5A27AE-9776-4096-BCFC-98599F16CADC)

[Create and use document Building Blocks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-document-building-blocks-in-Word-2007-60DBE504-0B7B-49F3-A9CC-271290041A50)

(Both these articles were written for Word 2007, but they still apply in all the essentials to Word 2013.)

Comment: yeah... but i guess there's no way to create master pages in word that can allow the user to create a background along with header and footer content in the master page and then apply that to different pages in the document... i hope MS introduces that feature in Word.

Comment: No, what I've described is as close as Word – or at least Word for Windows – currently gets to the functionality that you want, I'm afraid. If you have access to a Mac, Word for Mac has, or used to have, a Publishing Layout view that offered some type of master page functionality; this was never introduced into the Windows version though.